# SQL result should show all table one data

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have two tables as shown below:

#### table_one

```
teamid     teamname   description
   1           x         abcd
   2           y         dcba
   3           z         sadf
```

#### table_two

```
stageid   teamid   responses    score
   1        1        r1          20
   1        2        r2          30
   2        1        r4          20
   2        2        r5          20
   2        3        r6          20
```

I am trying to join the above two tables based on `stageid` number which I have. So, I am tried the following:

```
SELECT t1.teamid, t1.teamname, t2.responses, t2.score 
FROM table_one as t1
JOIN table_two as t2 ON t1.teamid = t2.teamid
WHERE stageid = 1
```

Which is giving me following result (*I tried all combinations of left, right, inner, outer joins*):

```
teamid    teamname   responses   score
  1          x           r1        20
  2          y           r2        30
```

#### Expected result table

```
teamid    teamname   responses   score
  1          x           r1        20
  2          y           r2        30
  3          z          NULL       0
```

As you can see in the above expected table, I want all the rows of the `table_one` and from `table_two` if the data isn't present, I need `NULL` or `0` as values.

How to do this?

Comment: Use different type of `JOIN`

Comment: `LEFT JOIN` will be your friend. The problem is, you've added a condition, `WHERE stageid = 1`. This will return only 2 records.

Comment: @lolka_bolka I already tried that as well. It isn't giving me the third row as I shown in the expected result table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT t1.teamid, t1.teamname, t2.responses, t2.score 
FROM table_one as t1
LEFT JOIN table_two as t2 ON t1.teamid = t2.teamid
WHERE stageid = 1 OR stageid IS NULL
```

By default when you use left join and there is nothing to join the fields gonna contain NULL, so you have to add NULL not just a specific stageid.

Or as others menthioned you can set the stageid like this:

```
SELECT t1.teamid, t1.teamname, t2.responses, t2.score 
FROM table_one as t1
LEFT JOIN table_two as t2 ON t1.teamid = t2.teamid AND stageid = 1
WHERE 1
```

In this query you use the ON tag of the join to set the stageid and you get the same result. (`WHERE 1` is not necessary)

Check JOINs: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6188334/2231168

Comment: Somethings I really easy which I think as complicated. Thanks :)

Comment: If you move `stageid = 1` to the `ON` clause you can skip the `OR stageid IS NULL` part.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to retrieve the non-matching record also then use `LEFT JOIN` instead of `INNER JOIN`.

**Query**

```
select t1.teamid, t1.teamname, t2.responses, coalesce(t2.score, 0) as score
from table_one t1
left join table_two t2
on t1.teamid = t2.teamid
and t2.stageid = 1;
```